# Aceitar apenas múltiplos de X no input

Tags: jquery

Preciso que meu input apenas aceite multiplos de um valor X que será definido via parametro da função.
Como posso proceder?

Comment: Melhor fazer essa checagem no `onblur`, pois *enquanto* o usuário está digitando o valor alternaria entre válido e inválido várias vezes. Quando ao cálculo, você sabe: transforme o valor do input num número e veja se o resto da divisão (`%`) pelo outro é zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer no evento `blur` do `input`, que verifica sempre que perde o *focus*:

```js
var X = 2;

$("#entrada").blur(function() {
  var numero = parseInt($(this).val());
  if (!isNaN(numero)) {
    if (numero % X === 0) {
      $("#saida").html("É múltiplo de " + X );
    } else {
      $("#saida").html("Não é múltiplo de " + X );
    }
  } else {
    $("#saida").html("Entrada não é um número.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="entrada">
<p id="saida"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a validação do HTML5 com um `input` do tipo [`number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html#input.number.attrs.type) que já faz a validação automática do campo e não deixa o usuário enviar o formulário caso o valor digitado não seja numérico.

Usando o método [`setCustomValidity(mensagem)`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity) você pode especificar uma validação com uma mensagem de erro personalizada. Para indicar que não existe erro, basta chamar `setCustomValidity()` passando uma string vazia como parâmetro.

A pseudo-classe [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) é adicionada ao elemento HTML5 que não passa na validação. No CSS você pode usar o seletor `input[type="number"]:invalid` para aplicar um estilo específico aos elementos com erro.

Exemplo de funcionamento:

```js
$(function(){
  // deve ser múltiplo
  var mult = 4;
  
  $('#num').keyup(function(){
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());

    if(val % mult != 0) {
      // [0] aqui é usado para acessar diretamente o elemento DOM, já que o método setCustomValidity é não é do jQuery
      $(this)[0].setCustomValidity("Digite um múltiplo de " + mult + ".");
    } else {
      $(this)[0].setCustomValidity("");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="number"]:invalid {
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="number" value="" id="num" /><br />
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```